# Do I get any notifications if my consumable IAPs are refunded?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cancellation

I have Apple iOS App with a lot of consumable IAPs.

I am very concerned that users buy IAPs and use them for a while, then complain to Apple customer service and get a refund.

Do I get any notifications if my CONSUMABLE IAPs are refunded?
How do I notice that and prevent the users from using IAPs?

Comment: 2020 and beyond: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705681/ios-iap-do-i-need-my-own-server-to-check-for-refunds/71808480#71808480