# iOS IAP - Do I need my own server to check for refunds?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

As a new iOS developer, I was surprised to see that over all the years it has been impossible to be notified if a user had refunded a purchase. I got that from questions like these:

- [How does Apple notify iOS apps of refunds of in-app purchases (IAP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439482/how-does-apple-notify-ios-apps-of-refunds-of-in-app-purchases-iap?rq=1)
- [Do I get any notifications if my consumable IAPs are refunded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258303/do-i-get-any-notifications-if-my-consumable-iaps-are-refunded)

Now as of 2020 it seems Apple has finally introduced a [notification for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/handling_refund_notifications). But this sounds like it only works with an **additional server**. I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

I do not have my own server. Can I still somehow detect refunds using **only local validation** (or a similar concept)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you need your own server** to accept & respond to the `REFUND` (webhook) notification(s) coming from Apple's App Store Server.

**There is no Apple-provided UI for viewing this data** as it is meant to be a programmatic integration with a backend service.

---

App Store Server Notifications is a **server-to-server** service as confirmed by [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications).

The language used in other official documentation, like the one you have linked or [this one here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responding_to_app_store_server_notifications), also clearly specifies the requirement for *your server*.

> When the App Store processes a refund, the App Store Server sends a REFUND notification to **your server**, at the URL you configured. **Your server** must respond to the post with a 200 response code.
>
> **Your server** is responsible to parse and interpret all notifications from App Store Server.
>
> When you set up the endpoints on **your server** to receive notifications, configure **your server** to send a response.